# How to use UnHandledExceptionHandler on android?

Tags: android

recently when I disconnect camera on my device. occur `nullpointerException`

so , I think use `UnhandledExceptionHandler`

I try this, first not occur `nullpointerException`

but app not start.
I want without camera device, app execute well.

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String nameOfFrontFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();

    VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice);
    if (capturer == null || capturer.equals("") == true) {
      Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnhandledExceptionHandler(this));
        throw new NullPointerException();

    }
```

UnhandledExceptionHandler.class

```
public class UnhandledExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private static final String TAG = "UnUnHandler";
private final Activity activity;

public UnhandledExceptionHandler(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread unusedThread, final Throwable e) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String title = "Fatal error: " + getTopLevelCauseMessage(e);
            String msg = getRecursiveStackTrace(e);
            TextView errorView = new TextView(UnhandledExceptionHandler.this.activity);
            errorView.setText(msg);
            errorView.setTextSize(2, 8.0F);

            ScrollView scrollingContainer = new ScrollView(UnhandledExceptionHandler.this.activity);
            scrollingContainer.addView(errorView);


            OnClickListener listner = new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            };


            Builder builder = new Builder(UnhandledExceptionHandler.this.activity);
            builder.setTitle(title).setView(scrollingContainer).setPositiveButton("Exit", listner).show();
        }
    });
}

private static String getTopLevelCauseMessage(Throwable t) {
    Throwable topLevelCause = t;
    while (topLevelCause.getCause() != null) {
        topLevelCause = topLevelCause.getCause();
    }
    return topLevelCause.getMessage();

}

private static String getRecursiveStackTrace(Throwable t) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
    return writer.toString();
}



        }
```

this not showing dialog.
how to use UnhandledExceptionHandler?

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught exception handler is supposed to be used only in the worst case scenario when every other mechanism fails. To handle NullPointerException, you should put that in a **try catch** block.

I suggest you look into Exception Handling in Java first.

UncaughtException handler- means some unexpected error occured and not allowing the app to crash can lead to unstable results.

Use it only to report or log unexpected exceptions, not as a defense against exceptions. That shows a flaw in the App design.

If you still plan to use UncaughtExceptionHandler, since you are not very aware of how Java works, I suggest you to use another 3rd party service to do this for you..

Eg---> **Crashlytics** (It has an in built default exception handler and reports crashes when they happen) or **ACRA** etc....

Comment: thanks,as a result I want without camera device, app is not died so , I want `unhandledExceptionHandler`